# Jenkins TestNG plugin does not fetch results from the test-results.xml file

Tags: jenkins, testng

In my project workspace, the test-results.xml file exists inside the target\surefire-reports\testng-results.xml directory. But Jenkins fails to read the XML file and gives below error on console.

```
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **\target\surefire-reports\testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
```

To ensure the file isn't too old, I had checked that the test-results.xml (and other files) belong to the latest test run. The Jenkins server is running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I'm running my tests in this manner: My project root directory has a `run_tests.sh` script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
    echo "Please provide a valid suite XML file name."
else
    mvn clean
    mvn compile
    mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="$1"
fi
```

I just pass the suite XML file name as a parameter to this script in Jenkins (execute shell).

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Krishnan, in the testng-users Google Group, pointed out that it could be an issue with my Jenkins project workspace, and it was the same.

I changed the default workspace in my Jenkins project.

So I've added the path "$HOME/myWorkspace/myProject/" in my Jenkins project workspace, and "**/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml" in my TestNG setting in the same Jenkins project, and it works!

Thank you Krishan for your help.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this.

1. Go to Configure of your Job
2. in General Tab, you may find
   Advanced Button, Click on this
3. Check the check box of "Use custom
   workspace", under this you see the Directory text box, here you copy
   your Selenium Workspace Folder, for example mine is
   "E:\eclipse\eclipse-workspace\WebDriveTest\"
4. Scroll down the page
   under the Post-build Actions, Publish TestNG Results,       TestNG XML 
   report pattern : give like this
   "**/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml" (check this path in 
   the same workspace).

I hope this will help you!.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `/` instead of `\` (since you mentioned that your Jenkins is running on a UNIX box)

Comment: That does not work either. It gives a similar error message:
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.

I actually tried with both / and \

Comment: How exactly are you running your tests on Jenkins ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the details of (1) how do you run your tests and (2) what are the contents of your shell script (`run_tests.sh` in your case)

Comment: I've added these details to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257657/what-is-the-testng-xml-report-pattern-for-jenkins-when-using-maven-with-surefire), it should be very clear.

In short, it is caused by the current directory was changed to the default Jenkins workspace, you need set your custom workspace in the Job's Config.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Krishnan Mahadevan usage of '\' instead of '/' while providing the path for TestNG Report also solved my problem.

Extremely important thing to note here:

When providing path for Root POM in the build section '\' is used

C:\Users\harsh\eclipse-workspace\ProjTwo3\pom.xml

When providing path for TestNG XML report pattern in Publish TestNG Result section
'/' is used

C:/Users/harsh/eclipse-workspace/ProjTwo3/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml

Console Output:

channel stopped 
TestNG Reports Processing: START 
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: 
C:/Users/harsh/eclipse-workspace/ProjTwo3/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml

 Saving reports...

Processing 'C:\Users\harsh.jenkins\jobs\MyApplication\builds\12\testng\testng-results.xml'

 11.688312% of tests failed, which exceeded threshold of 0%. Marking build as UNSTABLE

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31386450)